# How to calculate the transition between a transient and a steady state for a MG1 queue simulation?

Tags: python, queue, simulation

I need some help to give an output for the queue simulator I'm building.
Everything is ready, but I can't find a numerical method to discover in which piece of data the transient state ends and the steady state begins from data generated by the simulator.

I've already tried to calculate the variance of T1+T2 through the time and to calculate least-square approximation for the data function. Neither of them seems to be working well.

I have 2 queues FCFS and 1 server. All clients enter the first queue, and after being fully served they enter the second queue. First queue has higher priority than second. The info I get from the process is: T1 and T2 (time on queue + server for each queue), N1 and N2 (Number of clients in each queue).

Are there well-documented methods to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as the initial transient problem, and was first identified by Conway back in 1963.  You can get very thorough discussions of a variety of options in any modern simulation text book—search Google, Amazon, or Barnes & Noble for "discrete event simulation" and you'll get lots of hits.  Alternatively, [this paper](http://www.warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/wbs/projects/autosimoa/warmupreviewsimulation.doc) gives a reasonable overview of the variety of methods that have been proposed in the intervening half-century.  I recommend the MSER estimator by Pres White, which combines simplicity with analytical rigor.